# Getting error: "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined" using Jquery find() inside a filter() function

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

I have a filter function for a table.  The table has four columns that can be filtered: Client, Job, Due, Labels.

It worked fine when I filtered for the text of TD's that have a certain class.  But now I have modified the Due column so that some rows now have an Input instead of just text.

So I need to filter on the text of some rows and on the value of the input on other rows.

I tried adding the following line:

```
+ $(this).find(".filterDue").children().val().toLowerCase().indexOf(due) > -1 && +
```

But this line causes the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<td 
    class="filterDue" 
    id="dueDateTd{{ $key }}"
    style="{{ (strtotime($job['date']->format('m/d/Y')) < strtotime('now') ? 'color:red' : '') }}"

>
    <!--If the job has no Rrules it is a one time job so show the date as an input-->
    @if($job['one_time_job'])
        <input 
            type="text" 
            class="form-control input-sm datepicker filterDueInput" 
            style="max-width:90px; display:inline; {{ (strtotime($job['date']->format('m/d/Y')) < strtotime('now') ? 'color:red' : '') }}"
            name="one_time_job_due_date" 
            id="one_time_job_due_date{{ $key }}" 
            value="{{ $job['date']->format('m/d/Y') }}"
            onchange="update_one_time_job_due_date({{ $key . ',' . $job['recur_client_jobs_id'] }})"
        >
    @else
        {{ $job['date']->format("m/d/Y") }}
    @endif
</td>
```

```
$("#box_dashboard_client,#box_dashboard_job,#box_dashboard_due, #box_dashboard_label").on("keyup", function() {
    client = $("#box_dashboard_client").val().toLowerCase();
    job = $("#box_dashboard_job").val().toLowerCase();
    due = $("#box_dashboard_due").val().toLowerCase();
    label = $("#box_dashboard_label").val().toLowerCase();

    $(".filter").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).find(".filterClients").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(client) > -1 && +
        + $(this).find(".filterJobs").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(job) > -1 && +
        + $(this).find(".filterLabels").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(label) > -1 && +
        + $(this).find(".filterDue").children().first().val().toLowerCase().indexOf(due) > -1 && +
        + $(this).find(".filterDue").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(due) > -1)    
    });
});
```

I don't understand why this selector is undefined.  I can alert out this selector and it shows the proper output.  But it is not working as a part of my filtering function.

Edit starts here:
Ok, that fixed the error message.  But I'm also having another problem.  The filter function does not work when I include both lines:

```
+ ($(this).find(".filterDue").children().first().val() || '') .toLowerCase().indexOf(due) > -1 && +
+ $(this).find(".filterDue").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(due) > -1)
```

I can comment out the first line and the filtering works on the rows where an input does not exist.  Or I can comment out the second line and the filtering works only on the rows where an input does exist.  But I cannot use both lines at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the `@else` case. If the logic flows that way, the `children().first()` of `.filterDue` will be a textNode which has no value, hence `undefined`.

You can fix that by coalescing the falsy `undefined` value to an empty string:

```
+ ($(this).find(".filterDue").children().first().val() || $(this).find(".filterDue").children().text()).toLowerCase().indexOf(due) > -1
```

Comment: Ok, that fixed the error message.  But I'm also having another problem.  The filter function does not work when I include both lines:

`
+ ($(this).find(".filterDue").children().first().val() || '') .toLowerCase().indexOf(due) > -1 && +
  + $(this).find(".filterDue").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(due) > -1)
`

I can comment out the first line and the filtering works on the rows where an input does not exist.  Or I can comment out the second line and the filtering works only on the rows where an input does exist.  But I cannot use both lines at the same time.

Comment: I did not format my previous comment very well, so I added it to the bottom of my question for better readability.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Ah. In that case you need to put both of those in to the single line. I've updated the answer for you

Comment: Thank you so much!  I have been struggling with that for hours.